# method not printing all values in java

Tags: java, arrays

i have 2 java programs , the first one takes all information about the employee(id , name , department etc)from the user and prints it , the second program lets the user choose how many number of employees are there then it takes the values like(employ id, name etc), this program uses an array to store the values , it should print all values of different employees , but when i run the program the second set of values overrides the first set of values and prints the second set of values twice , im a beginner so plse help

This is the first program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class payroll2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        payroll2 payroll = new payroll2();
        payroll.SetPayrollDetail();
        payroll.SetBonus();
        payroll.SetCommission();
        payroll.SetNssf();
        payroll.SetNetSalary();
        payroll.GetPayroll();
    }

    Scanner myScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int empID;
    String empName;
    String empDept;
    String designation;
    int basicSalary;

    double bonus;
    double commission;
    double nssf;
    double netSalary;


    public void SetPayrollDetail()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
        empID = myScanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
        empName = myScanner.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Department (Marketing or Other): ");
        empDept = myScanner.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Designation (Manager, Executive or Other): ");
        designation = myScanner.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Basic Salary: ");
        basicSalary = myScanner.nextInt();

    }

    public void SetBonus()
    {
        if(basicSalary < 1500){
            bonus = 0.0;
        }
        else if(basicSalary>=1500 && basicSalary<3000){
            bonus = basicSalary * (12.0/100.0);
        }
        else if(basicSalary>=3000 && basicSalary<5000){
            bonus = basicSalary * (15.0/100.0);
        }
        else{
            bonus = basicSalary * (25.0/100.0);
        }
    }

    public void SetCommission()
    {
        if( empDept.equalsIgnoreCase("other") ){
            commission = 0.0;
        }
        else if( empDept.equalsIgnoreCase("marketing") && designation.equalsIgnoreCase("manager") ){
            commission = basicSalary * (30.0/100.0);
        }
        else if( empDept.equalsIgnoreCase("marketing") && designation.equalsIgnoreCase("executive") ){
                    commission = basicSalary * (15.0/100.0);
        }
        else if( empDept.equalsIgnoreCase("marketing") && designation.equalsIgnoreCase("other") ){
                    commission = basicSalary * (10.0/100.0);
        }
        else{
            commission = 0.0;
        }

    }

    public void SetNssf()
    {
        if(basicSalary < 1500){
            nssf = basicSalary * (5.0/100.0);
        }
        else if(basicSalary>=1500 && basicSalary<3000){
            nssf = basicSalary * (8.0/100.0);
        }
        else if(basicSalary>=3000 && basicSalary<5000){
            nssf = basicSalary * (12.0/100.0);
        }
        else if(basicSalary>=5000 && basicSalary<7000){
            nssf = basicSalary * (15.0/100.0);
        }
        else if(basicSalary>=7000 && basicSalary<10000){
            nssf = basicSalary * (20.0/100.0);
        }
        else{
            nssf = basicSalary * (25.0/100.0);
        }

    }

    public void SetNetSalary()
    {
        netSalary = ( basicSalary + commission + bonus ) - nssf;

    }

    public void GetPayroll()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\nPayroll Details \n _____________________");
        System.out.println("ID:\t\t" + empID);
        System.out.println("name:\t\t" + empName);

        System.out.println("Bonus:\t\t" + bonus);
        System.out.println("Commission:\t"+commission);
        System.out.println("NSSF:\t\t"+nssf);
        System.out.println("Net Salary:\t"+netSalary);

    }
}
```

This is the second program

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  public class display{

public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter;
    int limit;

    System.out.println("How many employess do u want to enter?\n Enter here: ");
    limit = scan.nextInt();

    int[] a = new int[limit];
    payroll2 payroll = new payroll2();

    for(counter=1; counter<=limit; counter++){
        System.out.println("\n\nEnter employee "+counter+" details\n");
        payroll.SetPayrollDetail();
        payroll.SetBonus();
        payroll.SetCommission();
        payroll.SetNssf();
        payroll.SetNetSalary();

    }

    for(counter=1; counter<=limit; counter++){
        payroll.GetPayroll();
        //System.out.println(a);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I believe you need to understand how object works, you overload your first payroll properties with the following. You need to instantiate an other payroll, and store all the payrolls before printing them in a second loop

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names and variable names are always written in camelCase, that means they start with lowercase. Classnames are in PascalCase, starting with uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the area of code that there's a problem in:

```
for(counter=1; counter<=limit; counter++){
    System.out.println("\n\nEnter employee "+counter+" details\n");
    payroll.SetPayrollDetail();
    payroll.SetBonus();
    payroll.SetCommission();
    payroll.SetNssf();
    payroll.SetNetSalary();

}

for(counter=1; counter<=limit; counter++){
    payroll.GetPayroll();
    //System.out.println(a);
}
```

If you think about what this does.  So a payroll2 object is a single entity.  When you enter them in the first for loop, you create one person.  Then if you loop through that a second or third time, you overwrite that person, since you are saving to the same variable.

Then when you loop through the second loop, you are printing the payroll entity, which holds the value of the last entered person.  Since the other data gets overwritten, its no surprise that you get the same guy printed limit times.

What you will want to do is build an array of payroll entities. This code accomplishes this:

```
payroll2[] PayrollList = new payroll2[limit];  // establish the array with correct size
for(counter=0; counter<=limit - 1; counter++){  // bounds of the array are 0 to limit - 1
    payroll = new payroll();  // hard reset of the variable to make sure data is cleared
    System.out.println("\n\nEnter employee "+counter+" details\n");
    payroll.SetPayrollDetail();
    payroll.SetBonus();
    payroll.SetCommission();
    payroll.SetNssf();
    payroll.SetNetSalary();

    PayrollList[counter] = payroll; // adds it to the array at position counter
}

for(counter=0; counter<=limit - 1; counter++){
    PayrollList[counter].GetPayroll(); // gets the payroll2 object from the array and calls its function
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not run the modified code through a compiler, so it may not be 100% syntax correct, but it is very close.